# Get current process saved set-user-id

Tags: ruby, unix, process, privileges

It's pretty obvious how to get **real user ID** ([`Process.uid`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Process.html#method-c-uid)) and **effective user ID** ([`Process.euid`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Process.html#method-c-egid)) of the current running process in Ruby with stdlib help. But I wonder where is a sibling method for the **saved set-user-ID**, something like `Process.suid`? There is only [`Process::UID.sid_available?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Process/UID.html#method-c-sid_available-3F) method, which allows to determine, does the running platform supports described feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are not going to like this, but AFAICT, this is the only way to get `suid` for the process.

```
suid = `ps -o pid,suid`[/(?<=^#{Process.pid}\s)\s*\d+/].strip
#⇒ "1000"
```

Probably one should check if `suid` is available upfront. Basically, this regexp searches for the line starting with the current process’ `pid`.

Comment: For MacOS `suid` should be replaced with `svuid`

Comment: Shorter version – `\`ps -p #{Process.pid} -o svuid=\`.strip`

Answer (score 1):

Answer based on this question: https://superuser.com/questions/1149421/how-do-i-find-the-effective-user-id-euid-real-user-id-ruid-and-saved-user-i

> The initial effective UID (as well as the saved UID) can be guessed here: since the file has the 'setuid' flag set, and is owned by the user 'anna', running it will create a process with the effective UID of the 'anna' user.

suid it's one of the attributes on the file, so we can just compare current process uid and owner id of the file

From documentation https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File/Stat.html#method-i-owned-3F

You can try use this method from stat:

> `owned? → true or false`
>
> Returns true if the effective user id of the process is the same as the owner of stat.
>   Examples:
>   `File.stat("testfile").owned?      #=> true`
>
> `File.stat("/etc/passwd").owned?   #=> false`

And if process uid and file owner not equal we can possibly say that binary has suid, and we can better determine is we have suid with next method from documentation:

https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File/Stat.html#method-i-setuid-3F

> `setuid? → true or false`
>
> Returns true if stat has the set-user-id permission bit set, false if it doesn't or if the operating system doesn't support this feature.
>
> `File.stat("/bin/su").setuid?   #=> true`

Comment: link-only answers are frowned upon because if the external resource gets changed, deleted or moved the answer becomes useless. Please post the relevat parts from the link here.

Comment: Thanks @bolov for comments to improve answer

Comment: Thanks @Cristic for comments to improve answer.

Comment: Let me resume your answer to make sure I understood it correctly. As far as kernel copies (saves) effective UID to saved UID on a process start, everything else doesn't matter (is `suid` flag is set or not) – we just check the executable file owner and consider it as saved ID (`suid`) – `File.stat($0).uid`. Or do I miss some specific case?